# What exactly are "variational quantum algorithms"?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory, variational-quantum-algorithms

I constantly see papers on "variational quantum algorithms" but I don't really see any explanation of what they are that are clear to me.

I found out about the variational method in quantum mechanics, which is an approximation to find the lowest energy eigenstate, but I don't see how this is related to quantum algorithms. (From [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_method_(quantum_mechanics)) wikipedia page)

Does the variational method allow for stronger quantum computation? Do the algorithms solve problems outside of BQP?

Comment: Try this page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_quantum_eigensolver and have a look at papers in References.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are algorithms having a quantum part with parameters (for instance angles of rotations gates) which are optimized by a classical computer :

[image]

Today's NISQ computers are noisy so algorithms using only full quantum processes can't give good results. Variational algorithms are a good alternative to take advantage of today's quantum computers.

Variational algorithm are used in Quantum Machine Learning for instance : the goal is to find the best parameters of what is called the ansatz circuit to get the best results (see for instance Variational Quantum Classifier).

Answer (score 2):

The review paper [Variational Quantum Algorithms](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.09265) gives a comprehensive introduction and analysis on variational quantum algorithms.